# c# Problema al enviar Bearer Token authorization desde consola

Tags: c#, api

Tengo un problema y es el siguiente:

Estoy tratando de hacer una petición asincronica desde mi consola, hacia mi controlador en el cual su función es enviar datos hacia mi BD y a la vez, enviarle un `Token` de seguridad( el token ya lo genero correctamente ).

Mi problema es que al enviar los datos y el token, me da `Internal server error` y no entiendo por que.

He hecho pruebas por POSTMAN, y funciona todo perfecto, excepto cuando voy a ejecutarlo desde mi consola.

Dejo mi código:

*program*

//aca genero mi token al autenticarme

```
  static async void Autenticar()
    {
        loginRequest login = new loginRequest();
        Console.WriteLine("Iniciar sesion");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("ingrese usuario: ");
        login.Username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("ingrese clave: ");
        login.Password = Console.ReadLine();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");



       var url = "http://localhost:49830/api/Customer/Autenticar";
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        token = result;
        Console.WriteLine(token);

    }
```

Acá envío mis datos

```
    static async void EnviarDatos()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Envio de datos");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        datos dato = new datos();
        Console.WriteLine("ingrese id de orden: ");
        //int p = 0;
        string pp = Console.ReadLine();
        dato.idOrden = Convert.ToInt32(pp);
        Console.WriteLine("ingrese estado: ");
        dato.estado = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("      ");
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dato);
        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var url = "http://localhost:49830/api/api/Ingresar";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

*Controlador (api)*

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public IHttpActionResult Ingresar(datos datos)
    {
        bool inserto = Metodos.InsertarDatos(datos);
        if (inserto == true)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            var message = String.Format("error");
            var errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
            throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pero cual es el error? puedes hacer un debug en el metodo Ingresar? Si el problema fuese que no estas enviando el token la respuesta del controlador  seria sin autorizacion

Comment: Siguiendo el mismo lineamiento que la pregunta anterior en relación a saber cuál es el error con mayor detalle o precisión podrías tener el código del controlador entre un **try catch** al menos para ver que excepción en particular te está dando y dónde.
Veo que lanzas una excepción en el caso del **else** pero puede que como bien dijo @MiguelZarate la excepción la esté lanzando el método **InsertarDatos**. 
Por favor, incluye un poco más de detalles en relación al error.